# How to sign-in to a Liferay server via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, authentication, liferay, external

I installed Liferay 6.1 in a sandbox server and want to be able to see a specific group/site blog entries from an external web page. This page will ultimately be running off a mobile device and may not have any indication of Liferay clockworks happening on the background.

I was able to figure out and use Liferay's neat JSONWS to fetch the blog entries but the login/authentication process is a bit nebulous to me at this point. How can I compute p_auth? How can I pass user/passwd/p_auth to Liferay via Javascript? In fact, do I even need to send p_auth in order to login/authenticate?

In summary: I need a javascript based webpage to be able to login/authenticate to Liferay and pull data via its JSONWS. Any ideas and/or examples will be *very* welcome.